# Connecting two rigidbodies with hinge joint in script Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to connect two rigidbodies with hinge joint when the hit each other. First one is scaling up on one axis until it hits the other(this is done by animation). This is script that I'm using:

```
private HingeJoint tempHinge;

public Animation anim;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision coll)
{
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Terrain")
    {
        Debug.Log("hit");
        anim.Stop();
        foreach (ContactPoint c in coll.contacts)
        {
            tempHinge = coll.gameObject.AddComponent<HingeJoint>();
            tempHinge.connectedBody = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that when this rigidbodies are connected the behave really weird, certainly not like they are correctly connected. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: add a Debug.Log each time inside your foreach loop.

Comment: check by disabling Animator if you have any on rigidbody as I had once physics problem because of animation it would not behave as intended so i had to disable animator if physics actions were happening